# How to resolve NS_BINDING_ABORTED in Nuxt 3 useFetch?

Tags: javascript, httprequest, fetch-api, nuxtjs3

I'm getting this error multiple times in the network tab (after resizing the view):

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
      at onConnectTimeout (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8522:28)
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8480:50
      at Immediate._onImmediate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8511:13)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
      at process.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
  }
}
```

### Network tab

[image]

### FE

```js
await useFetch('/api/test', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: bodyInfos,
});
```

### Server/Api

```js
// server/api/test.post.js

// post to db
await fetch(SUPABASE_URL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
   apikey: SUPABASE_KEY,
   Authorization: `Bearer ${SUPABASE_KEY}`,
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(testData),
}).catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

### Context

I'm building an analytics tool that fires an event to my database in an `onMounted` hook. However, due to this network error, my database is being spammed with thousands of entries. I've read that this only happens in Firefox. But I have this problem in Chrome as well.

I would expect that this api call will only post once, but after resize events it will just fire tens more and fill my database with the same entries.

### Questions

- Do I have to add an expire value to my header sending the initial call to my endpoint?
- Why does this error occurs in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed `useFetch` with `$fetch` and it's working now without any errors.

ps. I'm using the fetch inside a composable. [Here is one answer from the GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15528#issuecomment-1397383088).

tl;dr:
`useFetch` is for components using script setup. For composables use `$fetch`